python telebot KeyError:
Ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\popa.py", line 55, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1169, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop=non_stop, interval=interval, timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout=long_polling_timeout,      
  File "C:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1244, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 1206, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 150, in raise_exceptions       
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 93, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 8404, in _run_middlewares_and_handler
    result = handler['function'](message)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\popa.py", line 39, in handle_message
    if give_bonus(message.from_user.id):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Winner\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\popa.py", line 47, in give_bonus
    if user_data[user_id]['last_bonus'] is None or (now - user_data[user_id]['last_bonus']).total_seconds() >= 86400:
       ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 2019983510

Код:
import telebot
import os
import random
import json
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

user_data_file = 'user_data.json'

def load_user_data():
    try:
        with open(user_data_file, 'r') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}

    
def save_user_data(user_data):
    with open(user_data_file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(user_data, f)

user_data = load_user_data()


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_message(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        if message.from_user.id not in user_data:
            user_data[message.from_user.id] = {'balance': 0, 'last_bonus': None}
            save_user_data(user_data)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Привет! Я бот для нашей беседы.  У вас на счету {user_data[message.from_user.id]['balance']} дрочекойнов.")
    elif message.text == '/help':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "/help - список команд, доступные в боте\n/balance - узнать свой баланс\n/bonus - получить бонусные дрочекойны")
    elif message.text == '/balance':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ваш баланс: {user_data[message.from_user.id]['balance']} дрочекойнов.")
    elif message.text == '/bonus':
        if give_bonus(message.from_user.id):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ты получил бонус!")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Бонус не может быть выдан, так как ещё не прошло 24 часа")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id)
def give_bonus(user_id):
    now = datetime.now()
    if user_data[user_id]['last_bonus'] is None or (now - user_data[user_id]['last_bonus']).total_seconds() >= 86400:
        user_data[user_id]['balance'] += random.randint(3, 15)
        user_data[user_id]['last_bonus'] = now
        save_user_data(user_data)
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Помогите пофиксить

Ну значит нет в словаре user_data такого user_id, нужно проверять этот факт и заводить там юзера, если его нет. Если я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите.

Не особо понимаю про что ты, можешь сказать про какую строчку ты говоришь?

В ошибке даже указана эта строчка. Ты пробовал вообще ошибку читать?

Самая последняя строка кода в стек-трейсе ошибки. if user_data[user_id]['last_bonus'] is None or  ...
